# Routing between two components removes subscription from NGRX store

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing, ngrx

I have two pages in my application `Dashboard` and `Transactions` and a `Sidebar` component that controls navigation.

The first time I navigate from `Dashboard` to `Transactions` I subscribe to a user state in my store. Everything works as expected, I get the userID and inject it into child components to use.

```
export class TransactionsComponent implements OnInit {
  userID;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>, private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.spinner.show();
    this.store.select('user').subscribe(
      user => { if (user) { this.userID = user.uid; } }
    );
  }
}
```

When I navigate back to the `Dashboard` page and then back to the `Transactions` page I am stuck with the user ID never resolving and an endless loading spinner.

In my `Sidebar` this subscription disappears when navigating from the transactions page to the dashboard.

```
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  user$: Observable<User>;

  constructor(public auth: AuthService, private store: Store<AppState>) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.user$ = this.store.select('user');
    this.store.dispatch(new userActions.GetUser());
  }
}
```

Here is my effect that will retrieve the user ID

```
  @Effect()
  getUser: Observable<Action> = this.actions.pipe(
    ofType(userActions.GET_USER),
    map((action: userActions.GetUser) => action.payload ),
    switchMap(payload => this.afAuth.authState),
    delay(2000), // delay to show loading spinner can be deleted
    map( authData => {
        if (authData) {
          // User logged in
          const user = new User(authData.uid, authData.displayName);
          return new userActions.Authenticated(user);
        } else {
          return new userActions.NotAuthenticated();
        }
    }),
    catchError(err => of(new userActions.AuthError()) )
  );
```

I am expecting the `Transactions` component to keep the state of the user ID and not require a loading spinner when I navigate back.

Comment: You implemented a global state solution so your component doesn't have to remember the userID. This is a task for the store. If you aren't overriding the user in the store anywhere else, you should post more code in your question, because what you pasted there looks pretty normal to me. Do you think it would be possible to build a minimum reproduction on https://stackblitz.com?

Comment: Ok, I've added some more code in a place where the subscription disappears when I navigate from the transactions page to the dashboard page. I've also added the effect called GetUser that retrieves the user. Could this be part of the problem?

Comment: No.. nothing strange... maybe in the reducer logic? Also, in the component logic, you're starting the spinner on OnInit hook. Where are you stoping it? A Stackblitz demo would be fantastic to help you ;)

Comment: In the `TransactionsComponent` I think you need to dispatch one of your actions in `ngOnInit()` to get the user  `this.store.dispatch(YourUserActions.Load())`

Answer (score 0):

You have the right code in `SidebarComponent` with `user$` - just create an `Observable` instead of `subscription`.

In `TransactionsComponent` you need to use the same pattern, is there a reason to keep user `userID` as an independent property?

I would suggest you the next approach.

```js
export class TransactionsComponent implements OnInit {
  userId$;

  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>, private spinner: NgxSpinnerService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userId = this.store.select('user').pipe(
      tap(user => {
        if (user) { // we've got a use, the data has been loaded
          this.spinner.hide();
        } else {
          this.spinner.show(); // no user - looks like the loading is in progress
        }
      }),
      map(user => user ? user.uid : undefined),
      filter(userId => userId !== undefined), // <- comment in case userId isn't required.
    );
  }
}
```

and then in its template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="userId$ | async as userId">
   <child-component [userId]="userId"></child-component>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I am keeping it as an independent property to pass as inputs to child components. I have an add-transaction component I am hoping to use this ID when you add a transaction.

Comment: If you pass it further - why do you not want to use `async` pipe in its template instead of a subscription?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example how to pass to further components via the `async` pipe.

Comment: thanks for the swift response - I have attempted your solution however now as soon as I navigate from the dashboard to the transactions page the user state instantly disappears from the store. I can see that the user Id I am showing in my sidebar vanishes

Comment: could you share code of the `dashboard` template? is there anything behind the `spinner` service?

Comment: The dashboard component file is empty, it's basically just a HTML template at the moment. I'm only piping the observable in both the `Sidebar` and the `Transactions` Components. I've noticed that commenting out this line removes the error. `// this.store.dispatch( new transactionActions.Query());`

Comment: I don't see this line in your code. I would suggest to try smart / dumb component approach, and in smart one you can dispatch all actions you need to load data and in dumb one to have only inputs / outputs without observables and to render data. You can google it, for example this link: https://medium.com/@jtomaszewski/how-to-write-good-composable-and-pure-components-in-angular-2-1756945c0f5b

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into it and get back to you - If I need the user ID in both my sidebar and a page is it ok to inject this at two places? sidebar + page. Or should I be injecting at the shell and passing down?

Comment: if they are siblings it's fine to have store selectors in both of them, or to have a single selector in their parent component and pass to the via `async` pipe. If it's fine to have an empty userId - simply remove the filter from my code: `filter(userId => userId !== undefined),`.

Comment: if they are nested - then definitely the top component should fetch the data from store via `async` pipe and pass it further as a value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213387/discussion-between-matt-m-and-satantime).